# How to cast an object from its base class into its subclass

Tags: oop, object, swift

I have a class `User` which is a subclass of class `PFUser`:

```
class User: PFUser {
 var isManager = false
}
```

In one of my methods I receive a `PFUser` object and I want to cast it to a `User` object

```
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didSignUpUser user: PFUser!) {
 currentUser = user
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's an instance of `PFUser`, and not an instance of `User` stored in a variable of `PFUser` type, no it's not possible.

You can cast an instance of a class to one of its superclasses, but you cannot do the other way (unless the cast type is the actual instance type).

I suggest to implement an initializer in `User`, taking a `PFUser` instance as parameter - if that's possible.

However, although I never attempted to do so, I think inheriting from `PFUser` you'll just run into troubles, as my understanding is that this class is not designed to be inherited as it is for `PFObject`. I'd suggest looking into making `PFUser` a property of `User` - that way you can just assign as needed.

Answer (score 15):

This type of casting is a *downcast*. Given an instance of a certain *base* class where you know there exist subclasses, you can try to downcast with the typecast operator `as`:

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}

let base : Base = Derived()
let derived = base as Derived
```

Keep in mind though, that a downcast can fail:

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}
class Other : Base {}

let base : Base = Other()
let derived = base as Derived  // fails with a runtime exception
```

You can *try* a downcast using the *optional form* of the type as operator `as?`.

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}
class Other : Base {}

let base : Base = Other()

// The idiomatic implementation to perform a downcast:

if let derived = base as? Derived {
    println("base IS A Derived")
}
else {
    println("base IS NOT A Derived")  // <= this will be printed.
}
```

Comment: this definitely should be the accepted answer because IT IS POSSIBLE to do what the user is asking. It's called downcasting. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID341

Answer (score 8):

This can also be done by using the following:

```
object_setClass(baseClass, derivedClass.self)
```

However it is worth nothing that this uses the objc-runtime library which can introduce odd crashes if not used correctly.

Comment: Seems like dancing on a case of 80 year old dynamite, but worked perfect for what I needed to do.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript (including ES6), there isn't a concept of upcasting or downcasting like in statically-typed languages such as Java or C++. However, you can achieve a similar effect by treating objects of a subclass as if they were objects of their superclass. This is because JavaScript objects are based on prototypes, and you can always access properties and methods of the superclass from an instance of a subclass.

Here's an example:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} makes a sound.`);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  constructor(name, breed) {
    super(name);
    this.breed = breed;
  }
  
  speak() {
    console.log(`${this.name} barks.`);
  }
  
  fetch() {
    console.log(`${this.name} fetches.`);
  }
}

// Creating an instance of the subclass
const myDog = new Dog('Buddy', 'Golden Retriever');

// Upcasting to the superclass
const myAnimal = myDog; // No explicit casting needed, just assign the subclass instance to a superclass reference

// Accessing superclass methods and properties
myAnimal.speak(); // Outputs: Buddy barks.
console.log(myAnimal.name); // Outputs: Buddy

// You cannot access subclass-specific properties or methods
// myAnimal.fetch(); // This would throw an error since fetch is not a method of the superclass
```

In this example, Dog is a subclass of Animal. When you assign an instance of Dog to a variable of type Animal, you're effectively treating it as an Animal. However, you won't be able to access subclass-specific methods or properties using the superclass reference.