# Could not cast value of type UIView to [CustomView] using Xib

Tags: swift, uiview, nib

I've seen a number of similar questions, but many aren't up-to-date, and none have fixed my issue.

I have a custom Xib and class, `CardView`. When I try to instantiate it in code, I get `Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'CardView'`.

Class is as follows:

```
class CardView: NibView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var flipButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

and `NibView` is a custom superclass and looks like:

```
class NibView: UIView {
    var view: UIView!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Setup view from .xib file
        xibSetup()
    }
}
private extension NibView {

    func xibSetup() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view = loadNib()
        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view
        addSubview(view)

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[childView]|",
                                                      options: [],
                                                      metrics: nil,
                                                      views: ["childView": view]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[childView]|",
                                                      options: [],
                                                      metrics: nil,
                                                      views: ["childView": view]))
    }
}

extension UIView {
    /** Loads instance from nib with the same name. */
    func loadNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nibName = type(of: self).description().components(separatedBy: ".").last!
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my file inspector showing that I set the File's Owner custom class to CardView, which seems to be a stumbling block for many
[image: Here is a screenshot of my file inspector showing that I set the File's Owner custom class to CardView, which seems to be a stumbling block for many]

Finally, I try to instantiate the `CardView` as follows: `CardView().loadNib() as! CardView`

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875297/how-to-cast-an-object-from-its-base-class-into-its-subclass

Comment: Hey do you found any solution for this. I am also facing the same Issue.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still having this problem, I have the same problem and I think we follow same tutorial.

You have called `loadNib()` in your `xibSetup()`. I think you don't have to call it again.

So instead of using

```
let myCardView = CardView().loadNib() as! CardView
```

I just use

```
let myCardView = CardView()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `UIViewController`, when you create an instance of your `CardView`, instead of casting it like `CardView().loadNib() as! CardView`, you call the function `object_setClass(_, _)` to avoid that error (from Xcode 9).

So it should be like:

```
let myCardView = CardView().loadNib
object_setClass(myCardView, CardView.self)
view.addSubview(myCardView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone's here:

My problem was that the view subclass was `fileprivate`.  IB doesn't like that apparently.

Answer (score 0):

For me loading xib programmatically in this way doesn’t work. I had to remove File owner’s class name and set that to the class name of first view. And then I had to set outlets to the components which I’m going to use.

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

Added to custom view class after outlets. For you it's **CardView**. Then I loaded that view class like

```
let viewCard = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CardView
view.addSubview(viewCard)
```

Comment: How to set outlets then? I'm not following.. you can't connect outlets if you don't have owner's class. What I missing?

Comment: For custom .xib files, setting .swift file name only to first view and keeping File Owner's class to default (empty) is sufficient to set outlets. Then your assistant editor will assist you to set outlets. Make sure to set .swift file name to the top most view from the hierarchy.